# Where did the ASCII characters go? (Or: How can I convert this Python code to c++?)

Tags: python, c++, io, ascii

I have a file `text.txt` on my computer, which reads:

```
   I whispered, 'I am too young,'
   And then, 'I am old enough';
   Wherefore I threw a penny
   To find out if I might love.
```

I wanted to read this file with c++ and convert all characters to integers, including escape characters. I thus wrote the following program:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::ifstream t("test.txt");
    char c;
    while (t >> c)
        std::cout << (int)c << std::endl;
}
```

The output this file produces is

```
73 119 104 105 115 112 101 114 101 100 44 39 73 97 109 116 111 111 121 111 117 110 103 44 39 65 110 100 116 104 101 110 44 39 73 97 109 111 108 100 101 110 111 117 103 104 39 59 87 104 101 114 101 102 111 114 101 73 116 104 114 101 119 97 112 101 110 110 121 84 111 102 105 110 100 111 117 116 105 102 73 109 105 103 104 116 108 111 118 101 46 %
```

However, according to [this](http://www.asciitable.com/) ASCII conversion table I expected a `32` following the starting `73` to denote the space. Similarly, I expected a newline character `10` but couldn't find it.

In python, I achieve what I want with this program:

```py
data = open('test.txt','r').read()
for i in data:
    print(ord(i))
```

How can I do this with c++? IO is always a bit difficult for me, and I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: `t >> std::noskipws >> c`?

Comment: thank you, @ChrisMM